# Dialogue in Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine

How can I display an OS provided popup dialogue box in a Unity (4.6) game?

- The dialogue should block access to any other UI
- Should provide one or more buttons with callbacks attached to each button tap

Answer (score 2):

You can use plugins for this. 
iOS example:
download Prime31 Etcetera plugin and call

```
public static void showAlertWithTitleMessageAndButtons( string title, string message, string[] buttons )
```

more info here:
https://prime31.com/docs#iosEtc

Comment: I will definitely maybe check that out :-) I'm new to Unity and there is one thing that strikes me. Showing alerts is a very basic feature of iOS and also Android, does no one really care to use them in Unity? Also, all of the plugins available for Unity, why do they all have very strange looking web sites? How am I supposed to trust them in a professional environment. I need to get things done.

Comment: all Prime31 plugins are really worth it and kept up to day. Im using them for years now

Comment: The Prime31 plugins are really professional. Checkout the [documentation](https://prime31.com/docs#iosGeneral), the [twitter account](https://twitter.com/prime_31), the [release notes](https://prime31.com/releaseNotes) and the awesome [support Q&A site](http://support.prime31.com/).

Unity is a multi cross platform engine with the least possible amount of native functionality to reduce complexity, providing more native functionality than necessary is a risk, because those tend to break in a future OS update, even when it seems simple like a Popup, especially for all 15 supported platforms.